# ISC DHCP client: Where is the dhclient.conf?

Tags: process, dhcp, dhclient

**Problem:**

I want to change the timeout of dhclient for embedded Linux that doesn’t have DHCP.

**What I did:**

I have compiled DHCP from isc.org. 
I have compiled it with this CFLAGS:

```
CFLAGS="-D_PATH_DHCLIENT_SCRIPT='\"/sbin/dhclient-script\"'         \
        -D_PATH_DHCPD_CONF='\"/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf\"'               \
        -D_PATH_DHCLIENT_CONF='\"/ISGv2/configs/dhclient.conf\"'"
```

In my config file, `/ISGv2/configs/dhclient.conf`
(which I designated as `_PATH_DHCLIENT_CONF` in my CFLAGS, shown above),
I have specified a timeout of 3 seconds.

If I execute this command:

```
dhclient wlan0
```

It uses a timeout of *<something other than 3 seconds>*,
so it must be reading the "defaults" settings
from some other (unknown) config file.

If I execute this command:

```
dhclient wlan0 -cf /ISGv2/configs/dhclient.conf
```

it works as expected.

How can I determine what config file it is using by default?

Comment: What distribution? Did you compile `dhclient` or did it come from your distribution?

Comment: I have compiled the dhclient from isc.org. I don't understand the "pid". If I use the dhclient.conf (dhcpd -cf /ISGv2/configs/dhcpd.conf), it's easy to configure the dhclient, but with when the system uses the dhclient.wlan0.pid wlan0, I don't know which .conf file is using. Thanks.

Comment: As you compiled it yourself, the default path for the config file totally depends on how you have configured `isc-dhcp` before compilation. So no one can answer that except you. A typical location is `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. The option `-pf` gives a path to a file where it stores the pid, so it's easy for the system to find it later. This file has nothing to do with the config file.

Comment: (1) Do you want to mention ``/var/run/dhclient.wlan0.pid`` or not?  If not, delete it from the title. (2) Have you tried using ``strace`` to see what files it accesses?

Comment: Thanks Scott. Using strace I find the problem:open("/etc/dhclient.conf", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I don't know if there is a bug in the dhcp from isg.org, but it uses the dhclient.conf located here:

```
/etc/dhclient.conf
```